# How can I improve gaiter adhesive area on hiking shoe?

Tags: hiking, repairs, shoes

These are currently my go-to hiking shoes for basically everything now: [Danner Trail 2650](https://www.rei.com/product/154759/danner-trail-2650-hiking-shoes-mens). I love them. Also, I recently got a pair of [Dirty Girl gaiters](https://dirtygirlgaiters.com/). They are loud, fun, and functional. Unfortunately, upon getting them and setting up the heel adhesive, I noticed the poorly placed area for the Danner logo - conveniently on the heel (check link for visual). I went ahead and just put some extra Gorilla glue on the heel tap adhesive and just left it like that. I'm sure there's perhaps a better way to handle the logo obstruction that should otherwise (ideally) just be smooth to help with coupling with the glue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include useful images; links to retailers/suppliers are rather temporary.

Comment: **Most** of the Dirty Girl gaiters are loud.  A few are not and look reasonable when worn by men.  Don't be mislead by the name.

Comment: You might want to explain all that stuff about adhesive and velcro... For me gaiters are heavy-duty, waterproof things that come up to your knees - and attach very differently than the Dirty Girl gaiters you linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use a knife (or x-acto blade) and some sandpaper to remove the Danner letters making it smoother. Depends how much you value functionality vs looks (That's assuming you even plan to ever remove the Velcro).

Comment: If the one millisecond Gorilla Glue solution works, just be happy with it.

Comment: I don't think the Dirty Girl velcro is intended for removing.  Certainly not if he's using Gorilla glue on it.